# Regex to match all words not starting with digit

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

Sorry for the noobish questions, but i am not very keen with regex. I have several senteces like this:

`text1.2text:  text3,,text4 5. text6=== t7@ text8. T, 9-- T10` and i want to use a `scanner` to return:

**a)** single chars, **b)** words containing chars and digits but that do start with a char. 
Anything else can be seen as a delimiter.

So in the above sentece these should be returned:

```
text1
text3
text4
text6
t7
text8
T
T10
```

I could use multiple delimiters in scanner like `"\\.|\\:|\\,|\\,,"` etc but it could be anything in between the words i want to extract plus i do not this its a very good way to do it anyway.

Is there a regex i can use as a delimiter or maybe in `scanner.hasNext("regex")` to extract those words?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like this `(?i)\b[a-z]\w*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you mean, but it seems that you want to use as delimiters these parts:

```
text1.2text:  text3,,text4 5. text6=== t7@ text8. T, 9-- T10
     ^^^^^^^^^     ^^     ^^^^     ^^^^  ^^     ^^ ^^^^^^
```

which means that you want to split this string on every non-alphanumeric-characters (and optional words starting with number after it). If that is the case you can set up your scanner to use delimiter like

```
"([^\\w]+(\\d\\w*)*)+"
```

- `[^\\w]+` one or more non-alphanumeric-character
- `(\\d\\w*)*` which can be followed by zero or more words which start with digit
- `([^\\w]+(\\d\\w*)*)+` delimiter can repeat more than once (this way we will avoid returning empty strings between delimiters)

and simply iterate over `next` elements.

---

DEMO:

```
String text = "text1.2text:  text3,,text4 5. text6=== t7@ text8. T, 9-- T10";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);
sc.useDelimiter("([^\\w]+(\\d\\w*)*)+");
while(sc.hasNext())
    System.out.println(sc.next());
```

Output:

```
text1
text3
text4
text6
t7
text8
T
T10
```

Comment: preciselly. Thank you. just one questions. The last `+` is there to cover for example 2 white spaces between words. right? If that's the case couldn't i use `([^\\w]+(\\d\\w*)*)[^\\w]+` too?

Comment: @GeeKat88 `+` is for delimiters like `..2foo::3bar`. As you can see this string contains of two consecutive delimiters: `..2foo` and `::3bar`. If I don't use `+` `next` would return empty string between these delimiters. If we use `([^\\w]+(\\d\\w*)*)[^\\w]+` and delimiter will look like `::1aa::2bb` than `2bb` will not be included in this delimiter so it will be returned as valid word, while judging by your question it shouldn't.

Answer (score 7):

Use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
\b[a-z][a-z0-9]*
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/fY9eO6/1)

---

Since a word boundary looks for a spot where a word character (`\w` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) is next to a non-word character (`\W` or `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`), this means the example string `_foo` would not match (in between `_` and `f` is not a word boundary). If you need this to be the case, add a secondary zero-length assertion using a lookbehind:

```
(?:\b|(?<=_))[a-z][a-z0-9]*
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/fY9eO6/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you require matching the entire string, try this:

```
/^(\b[a-z][a-z0-9]*)$/ig
```

Tests:

```
tag1     // match
tag tag2 // no match
1tag     // no match
@tag     // no match
tag@     // no match
UPPERtag // match
```

[***Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/ujgfhx/1)