# Regex, how to match lines starting with non digits

Tags: regex

I`m a beginner of Regex. When I was trying to select lines starting with a nondigit character in this [test file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFV7m.png),

```
1 2012-01-01 12:00:00
2 2013-01-01 13:00:00
3 2012asdas
4 asdasasad
```

I tried 
`/^\D` and got what I want:

```
1 2012-01-01 12:00:00
2 2013-01-01 13:00:00
3 2012asdas
4 **a**sdasasad
```

Then, I was curious about if I could do the same job with `/^[^\d]`, but it just matched [all the lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49aAD.png):

```
1 **2**012-01-01 12:00:00
2 **2**013-01-01 13:00:00
3 **2**012asdas
4 **a**sdasasad
```

I then tried `/^[^\w]` and got the same result.
Thus, I`m thinking which part of the regex is wrong. The question might be trivial, but any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: you can have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350856/regex-to-match-all-words-not-starting-with-digit, i hope it answers your question

Comment: Which language you're working with ? it does work [`^[^\d]`](https://regex101.com/r/xjU7VA/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation:

- `\d` matches 1 digit
- `\D` matches anything that is not a digit
- `\d+` matches multiple digits
- `[\d]` matches all the characters in brackets which are digits
- `[^\d]` matches all the characters that are not in brackets, so no  digits
- `[\D]` products the same outcome as above
- `^` matches the beginning of the line

so `^\D+` will match line starting with non digits

You should try this really powerful regex tester here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thx for the quick response! I just wonder why `/^[^\d]` doesn`t give the same result as `/^\D`?

Comment: it does: `/^[^\d]+/.test('fgdl324532')` returns true as well as `/^\D+/.test('fgdl324532')` (in javascript - you can test in console)

Comment: I tried on regex101.com, and it does have the same effect. But why it doesn`t in vim?

Comment: this is probably because of that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604617/why-does-vim-have-its-own-regex-syntax